# My new jade plant

Tags: houseplants, jade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I help a sunburned jade tree recover?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/how-can-i-help-a-sunburned-jade-tree-recover)

I bought a jade plant from a lady about two weeks ago. I can tell it wasn't being taken care of. From experience (my mom having this kind of plant when i was younger) I brought it home watered it and since it was summer stuck the plant outside to flourish. I did not know it could sunburn. When I saw leaves turning brown and shrivelling up I quickly brought it inside. I believe my variety of jade is the e.t. Well I wanted to make sure my plant was healthy before I started pruning and replanting it. From the looks of the plant it has not been pruned for awhile.

My question is what would be the proper action to take to ensure the continued prosperity of my plant? I do not know how to post a pic of this plant otherwise I would.

Answer (score 2):

This [very similar question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/what-to-do-about-sunburned-jade-tree) has a great answer and [this one](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/how-can-i-encourage-a-jade-tree-to-grow-a-strong-trunk) is about encouraging a strong trunk.

Most jade plants do not grow really fast and very little pruning is needed unless you are aiming for a specific look like a bonsai tree.

Re potting a jade is not required for young plants if you want to see more top growth. They can grow very large in small pots.

For your plant keep in one place with bright indirect light and the new growth will be fine.  As you get new growth you can remove the sun burned older growth.

Edit: Re potting and pruning can be done in any order, just don't do them at the same time.  If this plant has got a bit sunburned I would let it recover for a few months before doing either.

Most soil mixes will do for a jade if you add some sand to improve drainage or you buy succulent or cacti mix.

A rooting agent is not necessary for jade plants. Cuttings can left to dry on the windowsill for a few days and then gently pressed into soil where they will grow roots and leaves.